# Multiple Content-Elements with Assets-elements breaking on what seems to be a specific number of images

Tags: ee2, assets, stash, error, content-elements

**Background**
So i keep getting an error when adding more images to the second Content-Elements field on one of my pages.

I have one for the maincontent and this one seems to work with an "infinite" amount of images.
The second one, who is also parsed last gives me this error:

> **Error**
>
> Unable to load the requested class: assets_lib

The first field currently has 3 Assets-elements with at total of 28 images.

When i try to add more than 4 images to the same kind of Element in the second field i get the error above?

I am not sure where to go next, is there a way to get more info out of EE's error manager.
A file and row # would be a nice start. :P

Is this a problem with Content-Elements or with Assets?

Is there anything i can add to help out?

**Versions**
- EE: 2.8.1
- Assets: 2.3.1
- Content-Elements: 1.6.9
- Stash: 2.5.1

**Template code**
I keep the Elements-part in a Stash embed, the part that handles assets is:

```
{assets}

<div class="row-fluid">
  {files}
  <div class="span3">
    <a href="{url}" class="gallery" rel="{element_name}_{element_id}">
      <img src="{url:150x150}" alt="{alt_text}" title="{title}">
  </a>
</div>
{switch="|||</div><br /><div class='row-fluid'>"}

{/files}
</div>
<br>
{/assets}
```

the part of the page template that embeds them looks like this:

```
{exp:stash:content parse="inwards"}

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span7">

    <h1>{title}</h1>
    {page-content}
    {stash:embed:components:content_elements_parser process="start"}
    {/page-content}

  </div>
  <div class="span4 offset1 subtopmargin">

    {page-content-2}
    {stash:embed:components:content_elements_parser process="start"}
    {/page-content-2}

    {page-modules-right}
    ...
    {/page-modules-right}
  </div>

  {stash:embed:components:social_share}
</div>
</div>

{if page-modules-bottom}
<div class="row-fluid content">
  <div class="span12">
    ...
  </div>
  {/if}
  {/exp:stash:content}
```

Comment: I am having this same error using Content Elements and Assets. I have my CE code in a Low Variables variable. It used to work, then I added some more conditionals for different element names, and now it's broken. Will be watching your question to see what develops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up ft.assets.php file (located at third_party/assets/ft.assets.php), find the method "replace_element_tag" and add this as the first line in that method:

```
$this->EE->load->add_package_path(PATH_THIRD.'assets/');
```

Sometimes EE would lose that package path and I'm not entirely sure why.

Comment: Works like a charm! :)

Comment: Andris - I'm getting the same error when attempting to edit an entry with an Assets field in the CP, and I applied your fix with no change.  I'm on the latest version of Assets + EE 2.7.3, any thoughts?

Comment: I had this issue on a custom module when loading up the asset_lib. Added Andris' line above "$this->EE->load->library('assets_lib');" and it worked a treat.